# Как правильно использовать виджет хлебные крошки?

Tags: yii2

Есть два вида скажем parent и child в паренте я использую хлебные крошки так

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

где  $this->title это тайтл страницы (их может быть множество и заренее не извастны) вопрос как можно использовать хлебные крошки в child так что бы первой ссылкой приходил   title parent c которого перешел пользователь  и ссылка на него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже учитывая, что получится сохранять массив крошек (пусть там в сессии, или переопределив класс view) все равно, обратите внимание, что код 
`$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;` создает не ссылку а span.
Ссылки в breadcrumbs передаются в виде массива 
`$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Название страницы', 'url' => ['site/page','id'=>$idPage]];`
Эти данные не появятся ниоткуда в child.

Кроме этого, можете взглянуть вот на этот ActionFilter, возможно это именно то, что Вы ищите [Yii2 Breadcrumbs ActionFilter](https://github.com/itnelo/yii2-breadcrumbs-filter)